# Isomorphism between $T^k_{l+1}(V)$ and $\mathcal{L}\left( (V^*)^k \times (V)^l\right)$.

Tags: tensors

V is a real $n$-dimensional vector space. I'm using the notation as in John Lee's *Riemannian Manifolds: an Introduction to Curvature* for the set of $\binom{k}{l}$ tensors and the set of multilinear mappings, which appear respectively on the title. Please note that $(V)^l = V\times ...\times V$ $l$ times.

I've tried doing it by first noting that they are both real vector spaces of the same dimension and building the following homomorphism
$$
\phi: T^k_{l+1}(V)\rightarrow \mathcal{L}\left( (V^*)^k \times (V)^l\right)
$$
which maps $A$ into $\phi(A)$. $\phi(A)$ is the multilinear mapping in $\mathcal{L}\left( (V^*)^k \times (V)^l\right)$ that should send $(w_1,...,w_k,x_1,...,x_l)$ into a vector of $V$. Here, $w_i\in V^*$ and $x_j\in V$ for all $i=1,...,k$ and $j=1,...,l$.

If I write it as $\phi(A)=A(w_1,...,w_k,x_1,...,x_l,x_{l+1})$, then I have 1 vector untouched on its argument (namely $x_{l+1}$), but that does not mean that $\phi(A)$ is a vector and, should it be, I can't say that the vector $\phi(A)$ depends on the other variables.

I wish I could get some help in this final step. Can I say that $T^k_{l+1}(V)$ is equal to the set of endomorphisms of some vector space? If I could then I would write $A$ in matrix form and try to figure out the rest.

Comment: It's on the question, "Please note that $(V)^l = V\times ... \times V$, l times", the Euclidean product of vector spaces.

Comment: oopss iamsorry.

Comment: it made me think that if it were $V\otimes...\otimes V$ with $l$ factors